# Reseed identity column in all empty tables

Tags: sql-server, identity

I need to write a query that resets the identity on all tables that have an identity column and are empty.

Answer (score 11):

Since you can reset the IDENTITY by issuing a simple TRUNCATE:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.'
  + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N';' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.identity_columns AS ic
ON t.[object_id] = ic.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
WHERE p.[rows] = 0 -- only empty tables
AND p.index_id IN (0,1)
AND p.partition_number = 1;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Though this will only work for tables *not* referenced by a foreign key. If you have foreign keys *referencing* these tables (likely), then you need:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'DBCC CHECKIDENT(N''' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.'
  + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N''', RESEED);' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.identity_columns AS ic
ON t.[object_id] = ic.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
WHERE p.[rows] = 0 -- only empty tables
AND p.index_id IN (0,1)
AND p.partition_number = 1;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a script to call DBCC CHECKIDENT ([TABLENAME], RESEED, 0)
over the tables resulting from this query (which will inform of all the tables with an identity field.

```
SELECT         
               t.TABLE_NAME
              ,c.COLUMN_NAME
              ,c.TABLE_CATALOG
              ,c.TABLE_SCHEMA 
FROM         
              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c JOIN
              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
                      ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE         
               COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(c.TABLE_NAME)
                      ,c.COLUMN_NAME,'IsIdentity') = 1 AND
               t.TABLE_TYPE = 'Base Table' AND
               t.TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
               t.TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'MS%' AND
               t.TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'syncobj_%'
```

Thanks to http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/06/27/60641.aspx